# Return a folder path using extendscript

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Using extendscript, could anyone tell me how could open a dialog box, click on a folder to highlight it, then OK the dialog and return the path to that folder as a string.

Many thanks
Bob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var myFolder = Folder.selectDialog ("Select a folder");
  if(myFolder != null){
    if(myFolder instanceof Folder){// <-- This is not really needed
    alert("path: " + myFolder.path);
    alert("fsName: " + myFolder.fsName);
    alert("fullName: " + myFolder.fullName);
    alert("name: " + myFolder.name);
    }
}
```